# Weak continuity for a possibly nonlinear functional on a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, dual-spaces, weak-topology

I am reading the fifth chapter ("Dual Spaces") from David Luenberger's *Optimization by Vector Space Methods* (1969). In Section 5.10, weak continuity for possibly nonlinear functionals on normed spaces is defined as follows.

[image: Definition of weak continuity for a possibly nonlinear functional on a normed space]

(Note: $X^\ast$ is defined previously in the book as the normed dual of $X$, and $f$ is meant to be the possibly nonlinear functional being characterized.)

I am struggling to understand the motivation behind requiring the functional collection $\{x_1^\ast, x_2^\ast, \cdots, x_n^\ast\}$ to be finite. In particular, instead of requiring a finite collection, why does the definition not simply demand the existence of “at least one element”, say $x_1^\ast$ (from $X^\ast$), which abides by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ condition?

Would greatly appreciate help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the way you define the [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology) on a normed vector space: Those finite intersections form a basis of neighborhoods of $x_0$, i.e. every weakly open set containing $x_0$ contains a set of that form for some finite collection. In this sense, those finite intersections are playing the role of $B_\delta(x_0)$ when you think of continuity on, say, $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The reason you can't just take one linear functional is that those sets are gigantic: Think of what happens when $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, then the set of $x$ for which $\langle x-x_0, x_1^*\rangle <\delta$ is a half-space! Requiring $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$ for $x$ in half-space is way too much. On the other hand, if you allow for finite intersections, you can get polyhedra containing $x_0$ instead, and that is more reasonable to expect of a continuous function.

Comment: I also wonder if and why the definition excludes the situation wherein an infinite collection $\{x_1^\ast, x_2^\ast, \cdots\}$ -- countable or otherwise -- exists corresponding to each $\varepsilon > 0$. Could you pls help me understand?

Comment: Moreover, does the definition require $n$ to be a fixed number, regardless of the choice of $\varepsilon$? Asking differently, does the definition mean that to each $\varepsilon > 0$ there must correspond exactly $n$ elements (not less, not more) in $X^\ast$ which take part in the $\varepsilon-\delta$ condition?

Comment: For your first question: The reason we can't allow infinite intersections is that intersection of infinitely many open sets need not be open. As for the second: No, $n$ can depend on $\varepsilon$, you just need for each $\varepsilon$  a finite intersection.